# Mudar layout de acordo com cada botão

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap

já vi muitos sites que mudam a `background` de acordo com oque o usuário escolher certo?

No entando seria possível eu mudar o conteúdo do site de acordo com o botão que o usuário clicar?

**Exemplo : Tenho uma página que exibe um popup `"Este acesso é pessoa física ou jurídica ?"`
 Se clicado `Física` exibe um conteúdo, se clicado `Jurídica` o popup será fechado e o conteúdo atual se exibirá.**

Tenho meio-caminho andado, tenho o popup exibindo a mensagem, e se o usuário clica em `jurídica` o popup se fecha, se ele clica em `Fisíca` redireciona para uma url.

**Ps: Sei que ficou bem grande, más tentei passar todos detalhes possíveis. Estou usando BootStrap**

[LINK UPADO NO SITE](https://ciclumtecnologia.com/alimentacaonatal-teste/)

Comment: Existem milhões de formas de fazer isso, você precisa ser mais claro nos seguinte pontos, o que exatamente precisa ser diferente de acordo com a opção e PRINCIPALMENTE, postar o código do que já tem feito...sem isso é tudo muito relativo e abrangente...

Comment: @KennyRafael Desculpas se minha pergunta não agregou de forma clara, porem fui claro sim em "**Se clicado Física exibe um conteúdo**" más para responder você, exibiria uma página com **imagens,textos,layout** voltado para uma pessoa Física.

Comment: Nos ajudaria se você pudesse criar um Fiddle para conseguirmos visualizar seu código

Comment: @LucasCosta Segue o link no post. upado no site da empresa uma campanha de natal. não postei o código pois tem bootstrap é muitos arquivos

Comment: Agora que temos a página, poderia informar em quais áreas você quer que altere de acordo com a escolha do usuário?

Comment: @ThalesChemenian falei com o front-end. Seria os textos, e o estilo de layout

Comment: @LucasBicalleto, tudo que as pessoas estão solicitando nos comentários são as informações que estava me referindo, se estivesse realmente claro todos teriam respondido sem precisar de nada. Estava claro a sua necessidade, o que você não deixou claro, foi exatamente quais ações e qual o conteúdo você possui, isso aqui é uma comunidade para que todo e qualquer conteúdo seja útil a TODOS, e não apenas a solução para o seu problema, por isso a necessidade de ficar tudo claro e de preferência, dentro da pergunta.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode criar as propriedades para ambas as classes de estilo na sua folha de estilo (CSS) e alterar o nome da classe usando Javascript em tempo real.

```js
var r = confirm("Cliquei:\nOK para Pessoa Físca\n CANCEL para Pessoa Jurídica");
if (r) {
    document.getElementById("formulario").className = "pf";
} else {
    document.getElementById("formulario").className = "pj";
}
```

```css
.pf {
  background-color: red;
}

.pj {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="formulario">Formulário</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ao acessar a página notei que você utiliza jQuery, o que já facilita muito, como você já fez a tratativa do clique e conseguiu identificar em qual o usuário já clicou, vou colocar somente alguns métodos que podem te ajudar:

Para alterar os textos você pode utilizar o método [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/);

Para adicionar classes [`.addClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/) e remover [`.removeClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/);

Para alterar o CSS [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/);

Para esconder elementos[`.hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) para mostrar [`.show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/)

Para remover [`.remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/)

Basicamente é isso, todos são simples e fáceis de utilizar e acredito que vão suprir sua necessidade.